# Setting a View translucent: Performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

So, looking for, *"How to make a View translucent?"*, I have encountered several answers with two most popular as:

Setting the background of the view to desired color(Initial). Then,

**Option 1:** Setting the Alpha of the view through calling `View.setAlpha()` to say, 0.6

**Option 2:** Setting the background of the view to a translucent background of the same color variant.(Ex: *Red -> bit transparent Red* and at runtime as per some user action, etc.)

However, [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) mention regarding `View.setAlpha()`:

> **Note:** setting alpha to a translucent value (0 < alpha < 1) can have **significant performance implications**, especially for large views.
>   It is best to use the alpha property sparingly and transiently, as in
>   the case of fading animations.

This greatly discourages me to call this method. This method is tempting indeed - A very simple one liner method call solves my problem but with performance cost.

So, now there is the second option. I want to know performance implications of both options comparatively and therefore the one that's recommended for use.

Has anyone considered the cost?

**Note:** The View could mean any View literally. In my case, simply a `<View/>`

Comment: Can you sent the background to NULL? I'm not fully sure what you are asking.. can you share xml or java code?

Comment: @Shmuel : Just Google for *How to make a View translucent in Android?*, you will understand quickly what I am saying. As for the code, it is just a simple View with no decorations or customizations.

Comment: @Shmuel : See, if my edit makes it clearer?

Comment: Is your question why transparency is expensive? See this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIy8g8yNhNk